# Makefile - Syntax error with for-loop

Tags: makefile, io-redirection

In a Makefile, I need to cycle through a list and write the current element of the list in a file.
The code is the following:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

LIST = A B C

test:
  for i in $(LIST) do \
    echo $ii > file.txt \
  done
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a <kbd>;</kbd> after `$(LIST)`. You need to terminate the list of words you are giving to `for` before you can start the `do` block.

As indicated in the comments, you additionally need a <kbd>: at the end of the `echo` line (the command that gets run has no newlines the way this works at the normal command line so you need to explicitly separate the commands from each other).</kbd>

And further, to get the results you expect, you need to escape the $ in the shell command by using `$$i` (also pick one of `$i` or `$ii` as your variable name).

Comment: @Giove You also need one before `done`. `for ...; do ...; done`

Comment: You also need to escape the shell variable reference using double-dollar signs: `$$ii` instead of `$ii`.